# Arduino Due for camera control?

Tags: arduino-due

Could one use the Arduino Due to control camera module like OV5642 and send the data to spi device? My project is to capture image with OV5642 and then to send the image data(RGB565) to other device via spi. For this STM32 must be enough, but I'd be happy if I can use the arduino IDE. Because it is much easier to program.

Could you please let me know, if you can use the Due for this task?

Comment: The DUE doesn't have lots of memory. Depending on what you want to do, that might also be a constraint. You should detail more what you want to do.

Comment: What I want to do is to take a bayer-raw image data from OV5642 camera module and then send the data to beagle bone black or whatever via spi. If it is needed, I can use frame buffer or RAM.

Comment: Why not connect the camera directly to the BBB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860620/interfacing-with-a-custom-camera-in-linux-on-the-beaglebone

Comment: yep, the arduino seems to be totally redundant in this scenario.

Comment: ah... I didn't want this situation. Actually what I'm going to use is not the BBB. It was just an assumption. The spi master will be some board not using MCU. So the question is, is the Due capable of taking and sending 5MP data? I didn't know that this is so difficult question to understand.

Comment: And please note that I'm not meaning Uno. This is ARM arduino

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an old question which has been abandoned for years without the specifics to make it answerable ever having been provided.  The only "answer" is really a comment to this fact, and none better are likely to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are still not giving the full picture, pun intended.

I'll give you an example of what sort of info is missing.

For example, what's the frame rate? What's the color depth of the sensor?
If you look at the SAM3x TRM, it says that the SPI is clocked at max 65MHz.

So, the (simplified) math would say:

24bit/pixel * 5Mpixel / 65MHz =  1.846 seconds

And that doesn't even account for acquisition time, so if you do not have fully working DMA on both sides, it's probably even worse.
And it will be worse, because you cannot stuff in RAM in one go the entire image.

But maybe that's good enough for you, however it's not possible to say because of the missing info.